# Webnoir website as Eclipse project, resources can't be found

Tags: eclipse, clojure, noir

I have this webnoir webapp as an Eclipse project. You can download it here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3914693/practicum5.zip

When I start it up, using the -main function from Eclipse, the resources folder doesn't seem to be found (I get a 404 on /css/tictactoe.css). What do I change to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: I needed to add the resources directory to the classpath...

Comment: project properties -> java build path -> [Add Class Folder] -> browse and check your-project/resources

Comment: additionally - add :require for each of your views
(ns your-project.server
  (:require [noir.server :as server]
            [your-project.views.common]
            [your-project.views.first-view]
            [your-project.views.second-view]
...